# Add Class to an element from JQuery Bootgrid based on information form Database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I have an PHP application which uses Bootgrid that fetch all the employees form the database. The thing that I would like to achieve is to set the class to the row of Bootgrid based on a value of a field. Here is the code from my `welcome.php`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var grid = $("#employee_grid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    rowSelect: true,
    post: function() {
      /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
      return {
        id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
      };
    },
    url: "response.php",
    formatters: {
      "commands": function(column, row) {
        return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " +
          "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
      }
    }
  }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {
      /* Executes after data is loaded and rendered */
      grid.find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e) {
          var conf = confirm('Delete id: ' + $(this).data("row-id") + ' termin?');
          alert(conf);
          if (conf) {
            $.post('response.php', {
              id: $(this).data("row-id"),
              action: 'delete'
            }, function() {
              // when ajax returns (callback), 
              $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
            });
            $(this).data("row-id"))
        }
      });
  });

  function ajaxAction(action) {
    data = $("#frm_" + action).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "response.php",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $('#' + action + '_model').modal('hide');
        $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
      }
    });
  }

  $("#command-add").click(function() {
    $('#add_model').modal('show');
  }); 
  $("#btn_add").click(function() {
    ajaxAction('add');
  }); 
  $("#btn_edit").click(function() {
    ajaxAction('edit');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-bootgrid@1.3.1/dist/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-bootgrid@1.3.1/dist/jquery.bootgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <table id="employee_grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0"
    data-toggle="bootgrid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id" width="3%" class="text-left" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Id</th>
        <th data-column-id="name" width="12%">Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="email" width="8%">Email</th>
        <th data-column-id="adresse" width="10%">Adresse</th>
        <th data-column-id="termindatum" width="10%">Termin Datum</th>
        <th data-column-id="terminzeit">Termin Zeit</th>
        <th data-column-id="useri">User</th>
        <th data-column-id="approved" width="10%">Approved</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would like to make evry row red color which has field 'Approved' with value of 0.
I tried to add this part of code in `loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid` but it didn't work:

```
grid.find("tr").each(function () {
  var $row = $(this);
  var isApproved = $row.data("row-approved");
  if (isApproved == "0") {
    $row.addClass("not-approved");
  }
});
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant/remove irrelevant code and add CSS etc to make a [mcve]